# Can't use retrained sentiment analysis model

Tags: stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

Not getting an error at all, the output is just using the regular corenlp sentiment analysis rather than my retrained version.

```
public static String filePath8 = "src/retraining/trees/model-0009-80.10.ser.gz";

private static StanfordCoreNLPClient init() {
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("sentiment.model", "Users/benit/retraining/trees/model-0009-80.10.ser.gz");
props = PropertiesUtils.asProperties(
"annotators", "tokenize,pos,lemma,ner,parse,sentiment,ssplit",
"ner.model", "edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz");
StanfordCoreNLPClient pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLPClient(props, "http://localhost", 9001, 2);
return pipeline;
}
```

I tried setting the second argument for the `props.put("sentiment.model", filePath8)` instead of looking for the file on my computer, and still nothing. The retrained sentiment analysis folder is also on my eclipse by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like this:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(...);
props = PropertiesUtils.asProperties(...);
```

So *after* your `props.put()` call you re-assign `props`, meaning you'd lose the values you added.

Try moving the `props.put()` to just after you assign to `props`. In fact, your first line isn't doing anything, so I think you could simplify it to:

```
Properties props = PropertiesUtils.asProperties(...);
props.put(...);
```